# Given a string s, find the length of the longest substring without repeating characters

Tags: javascript, algorithm

Example  Input: s = "abcabcbb" Output: 3 Explanation: The answer is "abc", with the length of 3. I tried writing this but if condition is never being exceuted. I am not able to figure out the reason.

```js
var lengthOfLongestSubstring = function(s) {
 let set = new Set();
    let c =0;
    for(let i =0; i< s.length; i++){
        if(set.has(s[i])){
            set.size =0;
        }
        else {
            console.log(c)
            c++;
        }
    }
    return c;
}; 
console.log(lengthOfLongestSubstring("abcabcbb"))
```

Comment: oh the reason is simple.. u log new characters until there are no new ones.. that's y u only get abc.. if you did `abcdefadefa` it would return abcdef

Comment: @Shilpi [Were the answers helpful?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the same algorithm as described by danhuong, simply written with a recursive call and no mutable variables.

```js
const longestSubstring = (str, i = 0, j = 0, found = new Set(), res = 0) =>
  j >= str.length
    ? res
  : found .has (str [j])
    ? longestSubstring (str, i + 1, j, found .delete (str [i]) && found, res)
    : longestSubstring (str, i, j + 1, found .add (str [j]), Math .max (res, j + 1 - i))

console .log (longestSubstring ("pwwkew"));
console .log (longestSubstring ("abcabcbb"));
console .log (longestSubstring ("abcabcbbvwxyz"));
console .log (longestSubstring ("abaca"));
console .log (longestSubstring ("abacdefg"));
```

Answer (score 7):

You can try this:

```
var lengthOfLongestSubstring = function (s) {
  let res = 0;
  let set = new Set();
  let i = 0;
  let j = 0;
  while (i < s.length && j < s.length) {
    if (!set.has(s[j])) {
      set.add(s[j]);
      j++;
      if (j - i > res) res = j - i;
    } else {
      set.delete(s[i]);
      i++;
    }
  }
  return res;
};
```

Comment: A very clean algorithm, and `O(n)` performance.  Nice!

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the actual character.

`set.size = 0` does not work. it is a read only property of `Set`.

Then you need to store the last found longest string and store it too.

Version with `Set` and without `count`, because `Set` has `size`.

```js
const
  longestSubstring = function(s) {
      let set = new Set,
          longest = 0;

      for (const c of s) {
          if (set.has(c)) {
              if (longest < set.size) longest = set.size;
              set = new Set([c]);
          } else {
              set.add(c);
          }
      }
      if (longest < set.size) longest = set.size;
      return longest;
  };

console.log(longestSubstring("pwwkew"));
console.log(longestSubstring("abcabcbb"));
console.log(longestSubstring("abcabcbbvwxyz"));
```

A version with a string only.

```js
const
  longestSubstring = function(s) {
      let sub = '',
          longest = 0;

      for (const c of s) {
          if (sub.includes(c)) {
              if (longest < sub.length) longest = sub.length;
              sub = c;
          } else {
              sub += c;
          }
      }
      if (longest < sub.length) longest = sub.length;
      return longest;
  };

console.log(longestSubstring("pwwkew"));
console.log(longestSubstring("abcabcbb"));
console.log(longestSubstring("abcabcbbvwxyz"));
```

Comment: okay thanks...but its failing for test case "pwwkew"

Comment: Each of these returns `2` for `'abaca'`, but it should be `3` (`'bac'`).

Comment: @NinaScholz Have a question on this. "kew" is also a substring without repeating character. but we are picking "wke". is this because of the condition that it's before "kew" and it's not longer than the prior substring("wke") ?